# Problem with natbib and french babel after migrating to El Capitan

Tags: natbib, babel

After migrating to Mac OS 10.11 (El Capitan), I have a problem using citations in my document. I have the following warning:

```
No errors. Warnings:

./Thesis_LP.tex:100: Package frenchb.ldf Warning: Please load the "natbib" package(frenchb.ldf) BEFORE babel/frenchb; reported on input line 100.
```

However I have made no change between the .tex versions, and under Yosemite all worked fine. Searched in forums without success. Any idea?

Comment: The warning is pretty self explanatory: place the command `\usepackage{natbib}` *before* the command `\usepackage{babel}` appears.

Comment: The fact that the warning appears on line 100 makes me think that you organize your document loading a package followed by related commands for each, then another package and so on. I suggest you load all the packages first and then all the commands for each package after them, followed by the document body. This way you have all the packages in close proximity, one after the other, and it's easier to change the order they are being loaded. The order of their commands is usually not a problem.

Comment: The message has nothing to do with your OS version. Are you _certain_ that nothing else has changed?

Comment: @Alenanno, thanks. The problem is that the class I use (custom class for phd thesis in french and english) load the package `babel`. The solution will maybe to load also the package `natbib` with the class, but I wonder why this worked before migration

Comment: @JosephWright, I'm pretty sure. However, I will check in my backup if really nothing has changed

Comment: @lorenzo did you make any progress with this?

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem with the thesis LaTeX template of my university. My solution was to go inside the .cls file of my custom `\documentclass`, find the `\usepackage` of babel, and add a `\usepackage` of natbib right before.